# Frobenius number of a local ring

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $(R, \mathfrak{m})$ be a (complete) Noetherian local ring (domain) of positive dimension. For each $\mathfrak{m}$-primary ideal $I$, let $e(I)$ be the multiplicity of $I$. Let 
$$\mathcal{A}(R) = \{e(I) \mid I \text{ is } \mathfrak{m}\text{-primary} \} \cup \{0\},$$ 
here we can think $0 = e(I)$ with $I=R$.

For example, $R = k[X^{a_1}, \ldots, X^{a_r}]$, $\mathrm{gcd}(a_1, \ldots, a_r) =1$, is a numerical semi-group ring. Then $\mathcal{A}(R)$ is the set of all non-negative integers that are a non-negative combinations of $a_1, \ldots, a_r$. The Frobenius number of $a_1, \ldots a_r$ is the largest integer that does not contained in $\mathcal{A}(R)$.

**Question:** Does there exist the Frobenius number for any local ring, that is the largest integer that does not contained in $\mathcal{A}(R)$?

Suppose $R$ is a domain. It is worth noting that $\mathcal{A}(R) = \mathbb{N}$ if and only if $R$ is regular by Nagata's theorem.

Comment: Is this equivalent to asking whether there are only finitely many nonnegative integers not contained in $\mathcal A(R)$? (because every finite nonempty set of integers has a largest element)

Comment: Hi Pham, can you clarify the statement:  "Then $A(R)$ is the set of all non-negative integers represented by $a_1,…,a_r$ with non-negative coefficients."  What do you mean represented by?

Comment: @KarlSchwede I think from context he means nonnegative integer combinations of $a_1,\dots,a_r$, as then the statement is (almost) correct. (He needs to assume that $\gcd(a_1,\dots,a_r)=1$ and he should say that $\mathcal A(R)$ consists of positive integers, as $1$ is not $\mathfrak m$-primary.)

Comment: Thanks Karl and Will. All your comments are correct. I edit the question.